# Applications of orthogonal trajectories

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations

**Question**

Do you know any application or in which field this trajectories can be applied?

*Comment*

If you know any book or any site that can show me the applications, please let me know. Thanks for your time

Comment: This trajectories means what!

Comment: http://books.google.es/books?id=lIBCltUml6oC&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=%22+applications+of+Orthogonal+trajectories%22&source=bl&ots=RPlxiLRXOH&sig=M9TmAywcDv-SGTC4CPHMZkhxvN8&hl=ca&ei=uy2MTLvHD8WI4AbE7cCTCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5&ved=0CCoQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22%20applications%20of%20Orthogonal%20trajectories%22&f=false

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you mean is how differential equations can be applied to find othogonal trajectories?

http://www.sosmath.com/diffeq/first/orthogonal/orthogonal.html

Answer (score 0):

in my book it is written " Orthogonal trajectories are very important in many applications specially in electricity and magnetism and in the construction of meteorological maps "
but i do not know really that does last word mean :D

Comment: It would probably have been nice to include your book's title...

Comment: It is not a textbook it is just a small book of on the instructors in our college